# SSRS Calculated Series MACD Chart Conditional Format

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have created a MACD chart using Calculated series. Please see here[image: MACD Chart Created]. Now I wanted to change the colour for an e.g. when MACD is Positive Black and red when negative. I have tried to use below syntax`=IIF(Value>0,"black","Red")` under FILL Colour Expression area. But I am getting the error message [image: here]

can someone help me how to change colour of the MACD Chart to Black when its Positive and Red when its negative. Thank you..

Comment: I don't think this is possible see a similar post here https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/6af0bea4-ed0b-462d-bc93-975694e07d96/ssrs-2008r2-how-can-i-access-the-value-of-a-derived-calculated-series-in-a-chart?forum=sqlreportingservices

The only way would be to calculate this series in your dataset query and then it will be available as a normal series.